# Do images that have been removed remain hosted?

Tags: support, images, hosting

Say I add an image to an answer. It's hosted on https://i.stack.imgur.com/ like all images here are. Then say I remove it from my answer for whatever reason.

Does this image remain hosted by i.stack.imgur.com? I know that Imgur doesn't remove images, but I don't know if StackExchange's version does the same.

The reason why I ask now is because I think an answer of mine with images may be removed and I don't really want to re-host them because I avoid additional work whenever possible.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Will links to images be kept permanently when added to a comment and nothing else?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251881/168244)

Comment: "I avoid additional work whenever possible." http://i.stack.imgur.com/mtYp4.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the arrangement Stack Exchange has with Imgur will mean that the image will remain hosted even if there are no questions linking to the image.

However, in your case even if you delete your answer it will still exist (and be visible to diamond moderators and those users with >10k reputation (>4k on beta sites)) so there will still be something linking to your image anyway.

If you edit your answer then the previous revisions will still exist and point to the image too. So I think you can safely say that the image will always<sup>*</sup> exist.

* for various definitions of "always".

Comment: I suppose that's true for revisions as well then. The only situation I can think of the link *not* being there is if it's taken out within the editing stage or within the first 5 minutes of an edit