# My inbox takes me to the wrong question when question is closed as dup and I'm not logged in on target site?

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, notifications, global-inbox

I have an incognito browser window open that is logged into Programmers, but not to StackOverflow. I have a separate browser window that is logged into all SE sites. (If you must know, my [StayFocused](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stayfocusd/laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji?hl=en) time is expired so I'm using an incognito window to access Programmers)

I clicked on an inbox notification from my incognito browser for a comment reply on a SO question that has been closed as a duplicate, however clicking the link takes me to the linked duplicate question instead of the comment reply on the closed question (it also looks a bit funny to me, as the ads are suppressed but space is still blocked out for them).

[image]

The exact link my Inbox gives me is https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/20442845

If I use this in my regular browser window, it gets translated correctly into [How to automatically resize a font for a given height and width when creating an image (e.g. .jpeg)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634060/how-to-automatically-resize-a-font-for-a-given-height-and-width-for-a-image-e-g#comment20442845_14634060)

But if I use this in my incognito window that isn't logged into SO, it gets translated to [How to grow/shrink a TextBlock (Font Size) to the available space in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794355/wpf-4-grow-shrink-textblock-font-size-based-on-available-space#comment20442845_14634060)

This does not happen with other SO inbox notifications from the incognito browser window, so I'm assuming it has something to do with the question being closed as a duplicate.

Soooo I figured I'd be a good citizen and report it as a bug :)

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the situation, that is by design I believe.

Comment: So, installing a productivity app just to circumvent it? [It's time we had a talk.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11652/188613)

Comment: @Bart Hrrmm why would it be by-design to give you a comment notification that doesn't take you to the post the comment is on?

Comment: I believe non-logged-in users are automatically redirected to the duplicate when visiting a link to a closed-as-dupe question. Is that not the situation here?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar You should have seen how much time I spent on SE sites before I installed it...  :) It really does help me keep track of how long I spend on non-work sites, even if I do bypass it some days to get work-related answers from other SE sites, or decide to come in early to work on stuff and want to spend a little extra time on SE during the day to make up for it.

Comment: @Bart Technically yes, but the `/posts/comments/#` route probably should probably check if that redirect is going to occur in advance and send a no-redirect flag when necessary, since obviously you don't get where it intended you to go in this case.

Comment: This seems a little edge-casey. This would happen for *any* notification that would link you back to that post. If you're not logged in, it's going to redirect you, and I don't see coding in checks to determine if it was a notification or whatever the case to be valuable in the long-run. The only viable solution here is login and view it. However, I do think the behavior is a little confusing. There should be some sort of small notice outlining "You have been redirected here from another question. Please login to avoid this." or something.

Comment: @TimStone That sounds entirely reasonable...I hate reasonable.... ;)

Comment: @TimStone: As far as I'm aware, the `noredirect` URL flag doesn't work for duplicate redirects for unauthenticated users. As well, how would the system know before-hand that you're not currently logged in on the other site?

Comment: @animuson I think the important factor with this link is it is a link for the comment, not for the post. Links to comments should not redirect you to another post that doesn't contain that comment :)

Comment: @Rachel: What if it was a notification that someone edited your answer to the question? It would still redirect you to the other post which doesn't have your answer. There are more use-cases than just comments here.

Comment: @animuson It could be made to, surely. All the system has to know when you hit the `/posts/comments/#` route is that the question it will redirect to is closed in such a way as to cause a redirection, and then instead serve up the flagged URL appropriately. Since that route is used for viewing comments, it "knows" if you're hitting it it should make a best-effort to get you to the comment.

Comment: @TimStone: It does seem to work. I suppose they could just always append a `noredirect` to those links. Is there any real harm in that? Seems like adding a check is a waste of effort for such a slim-occurring scenario.

Comment: @animuson Yeah, that seems fine too. I didn't know if there was any potential downside to throwing that flag on when it wasn't necessary, but I can't think of why there would be. This is a bit of an edge case, but I don't think it's too much effort to eventually resolve either.

Comment: There are a few edge cases where the automatic redirect is confusing, e.g. also when linking them from a meta site. [I proposed to disable it for users with a referrer from an SE site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146561/disable-the-automatic-redirect-to-duplicates-when-the-referrer-is-an-se-site), which should get rid of the edge cases. These edge cases are rather rare, but they are quite confusing when they happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with the next build, we'll start appending the "noredirect=1" magic slug to items in the inbox.

This will suppress most of the redirects that could happen when coming from a link in the inbox.