# Please show me that I cannot post pictures before trying to send the question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, images, usability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warn new users earlier that they cannot post links or images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129833/warn-new-users-earlier-that-they-cannot-post-links-or-images)

It would be nice if I could get a message instantly when trying to embed a picture although I am not allowed to. I wrote a long question with several pictures embedded only to get the error message that I cannot do that when trying to post the question and had to rewrite the image codes.

How about checking if a user is allowed to post pictures when he clicks the Image icon in the icon bar? Or showing a warning above the editor.

Comment: I posted that feature request a while ago: [Warn new users earlier that they cannot post links or images](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129833/warn-new-users-earlier-that-they-cannot-post-links-or-images). The same issue exists for images and links, though it would be easier to fix for images (as links are more likely to be inserted by hand, and for images just disabling the button with a tooltip should be enough).