# Remove the restricton of attaching images with low reputation

Tags: feature-request, new-users, privileges, images

I think preventing newbies to attach image to the question is unnecessary. I could add links  to the images I want to attach, so the first reader with high reputation will edit my post and add it as a image. So why this restriction? It just force Stack Overflow users to double work (bit work, but double)

Comment: @hims056 - It is not a duplicate of that. The requests are different. This request is to remove the reputation requirement entirely. That one is to institute an approval workflow.

Comment: @MartinSmith but that other one resulted in removing the restriction anywhere outside the biggest 4 sites.

Comment: @RalZarek - I hadn't seen that answer. Actually that seems completely counterintuitive. On the larger sites such as StackOverflow any abuse will be dealt with *more* quickly. I can't imagine a blatant spam or NSFW image lasting more than 2 minutes on SO.

Answer (score 21):

If you remove this restriction, you add another tool for users that want to troll the site. Being able to post NSFW images of all kinds could cause a lot of trouble. There are all kinds of images floating around the internet that you regret ever looking at, I think it could be a bit too dangerous to allow any user to plaster those across the site.

This is a point where you have to decide between the potential harm done by the restriction and the potential benefit. How harmful this restriction is depends a lot on the specific site, on SO posting an image is rather uncommon, most questions consist of some text and a code block. On sites like Photo or DIY posting an image is very common, so the restriction should be disabled there (and it is, I think).

What we should do is to make it clearer to new users that they can't add images and [warn them earlier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129833/151385), the current UI is rather bad and misleading in that aspect.

Comment: It's only once an image is uploaded that a red box full of text that says "You need a minimum of 10 reputation to post images".

Comment: The red box @Qantas94Heavy mentions is OK, but it should end with "Link to imgur copy added instead". And of course that's how it should work - images are uploaded anyway, so why not to link to them? Users would see it's a link by low-rep so they would be able to choose if they wanna see it or not.