# What should new users do if they have to add a graph in the question?

Tags: support, new-users, images

Why can’t new users add images to their *first* questions?

Suppose there is a homework question that cannot be typed. If the user can’t add an image (of course followed by his working), then how will he able to actually ask?

By *questions that can’t be typed,* I mean that the core content of the question is based on an image, like a graph or a pie chart or a visual-output-based image.

I have read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202406/remove-the-restricton-of-attaching-images-with-low-reputation) and the links that follow it . This is not a dupe. ( It might come under feature-request though I am not sure )

Comment: If you can't type your question and need to post an image, you are almost certainly asking a bad question.  Ask a question about a specific issue you are having trying to solve your homework, don't just ask someone to do your homework for you.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I meant , questions where the user cant type it , like including a graph .

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens: Yes, there were some valuable suggestions in your edit, but there also were some negative ones, like introducing big headings for two paragraphs, emphacising where it does not make sense and similar. I found that the negative aspects were outweighing the positive ones and thus I chose *Reject and Edit* instead of *Approve and Edit.*

Comment: 1 more comment to illustrate what I mean (and like ...): http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/164035/revisions ... Because it appears to me like real collaboration.