# Update "Remove New User Restrictions" page to include new user also can't post images, on sites where this restriction exists

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, new-users, images, help-center

On some sites in Stack Exchange, for example Stack Overflow, when user with 10 or less reputation points try to submit a post containing embedded images (i.e. `![][...]` markup or direct `<img>` tag) he will be greeted with such error:

> [image]

Fair enough, it was [already suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129833/152859) to improve this behavior but I ask for something else.

The current [remove new user restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) help center page says:

> New users cannot:
>
> - post more than two hyperlinks at a time, either in a post or their user profile
> - contribute answers to protected questions
> - ask or answer questions too rapidly

Images are not mentioned at all.

Can you please add another item saying new users cannot post images as well, in the relevant sites?

Comment: IIRC privilege pages can be edited by users with more than 2k rep on meta.so on the [privileges page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user). You have the necessary rep, I don't. Do it.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn not anymore, it was possible before the help center was introduced and now only moderators can edit those pages. Also, here on Meta user with 1 rep can post images so it will be wrong.

Comment: Argh. This should be reintroduced. (Or did someone do stupid things with that?)

Comment: @JohannesKuhn feel free to start such feature request, but I highly doubt the team will do that - maybe you'll get some official answer as to "why" though. :)

Comment: As far as I remember that restriction was removed for most sites, so this text would have to be adjusted on a per-site level

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd [Done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209527/allow-users-with-enough-reputation-on-meta-so-to-edit-the-privileges-page)

Comment: @Mad true, updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've noted, [this restriction only applies on certain sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258875/335251), where the relevant site setting is enabled. However, we can't customize the privilege help pages on a per-site basis, as far as I know; the privilege descriptions themselves are identical network-wide. As such, we can't do this. However, users are informed about these restrictions elsewhere in the interface, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Perhaps we could put an asterix somewhere and say that other per-site limitations may apply?