# Which SE sites require 10 reputation points to post images?

Tags: support, new-users, privileges, images

On most Stack Exchange sites, new users can embed images in posts regardless of reputation. But there are a few sites where embedded images are not accepted from users with reputation less than 10. What are they?

Comment: Related: [list of sites that require registration to post a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227114/259867)

Answer (score 17):

As of now, the following sites only allow users with the "[remove new user restrictions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user)" privilege (granted at 10 reputation) to embed images in their posts:

- [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/)
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)
- [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/)
- [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/)
- [Personal Finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/)
- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) (in English)
- [Stack Overflow in Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)
- [Super User](https://superuser.com/)
- [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/)

(Sources: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195927/259867), [2](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20730/147263))

---

To request that image embedding should be disabled for new users on that site, post a new question on your site's meta. Ensure that the post clearly presents a case for why this change should be made.

If the community supports the requested change, the site's moderators can add the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag to that meta post to [escalate it for staff attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/335251). The CMs will then assess the request and handle it accordingly.