# Did someone disable the minimum rep check for posting images to questions? Things are getting a lot spammier now

Tags: support, privileges, images, spam

Seems like we're getting a smidge more in the way of network spam in regards to users posting images in their questions with only 1 rep, most of it spam-oriented.

Comment: Which sites? That rule is only active at a handful of sites: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258876/295232

Comment: I had thought this was universal.  I saw a few here on Meta Stack Exchange and on Anime and Manga.

Comment: Yes, we get quite a few image-only posts (mostly answers though) on Meta.SE. But it's ... manageable so far.

Comment: Meta SE seems to get them at a disproportionately higher rate than the other sites (looking at past Smokey reports).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog:  Not really...?

Comment: oh the irony...

Comment: @KevinB well, the spam answer to this question did not contain any images. Coincidence? Nobody knows ...

Comment: I was kinda disappointed that it didn't contain an image, tbh