# Is an account needed to post images on Stack Exchange using Imgur?

Tags: discussion, images

How do I post images on Stack Exchange using Imgur? Do I have to make an account on Imgur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built-in uploader without an Imgur account. You don't even need an account on Stack Exchange to use it.

It's best to use a question draft on a site that doesn't [require registration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227114/323179), since you can't accidentally submit a question with no title or tags. Otherwise, you can access the editor on most sites by pretending to edit a post (just don't submit it!).

You should see this icon in the formatting bar above where you type your post:

[image: Landscape photo icon]

Clicking on it, or typing <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd>, will open a dialogue where you can either paste an image/image URL (<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>), browse files on your system to upload, or type a URL to upload from.

After the image is uploaded, it is automatically inserted into the post.

On some sites, users with <10 rep are not allowed to post images (see [Warn new users earlier that they cannot post links or images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267491/323179)). The image will still be uploaded to i.stack.imgur.com, but it will be displayed as a link, not an image. Links have the same format as images, except they don't have an exclamation point at the beginning.